# Connect Google Data Studio to PostgreSQL using local host

Tags: sql, postgresql, looker-studio

I am trying to connect Google Data Studio to PostgreSQL using my local host, but it throws me an error. I have also tried using the `inet_server_address` as local host, provided by using the following command:

```
select inet_server_addr( ), inet_server_port( );
```

This is the error I get:
[image: ds]

Answer (score 1):

Data Studio does not run locally so it can't connect to your server using `localhost` hostname. Your best bet is to expose the local server to internet and putting in your public IP in the config for Data Studio.